# Gateway Laptop boots to BIOS, but not OS

Tags: laptop, bios, gateway

I have a [Gateway MP8708](http://support.gateway.com/s/Mobile/Q106/SonicC/1013924Rnv.shtml). These are the following symptoms:

1. able to boot to and enter BIOS

   - can change BIOS settings and remembers them
   - does not show any problems during BIOS boot
2. can push F10 to enter 'BoOt from...' menu.

   - lists items and detects: DVD Drive, USB Drive (if I connect it to USB), HD

It attempted to boot the OS, but I just get a blank screen.

I took the HD out and connected it to my PC. It worked well. I erased the drive.

Anyone have any ideas on what else I can do to see what is broken? I took the entire laptop apart and didn't see anything too obvious.

**Edit:**

I should have added, I inserted a CD drive to install a new OS. but it will not read it. nor will it read a usb drive, so i cannot re-install the os.

Comment: Have you tried re-installing an operating system now that you erased the drive?

Comment: I should have added, I inserted a CD drive to install a new OS. but it will not read it. nor will it read a usb drive, so i cannot re-install the os.